# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) - FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm getting 'Null check operator used on a null value' on my profile page. Profile page:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Perfil extends StatelessWidget {
  const Perfil({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 172, 178),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Perfil'),
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text("Email:",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Text(user.email!,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Degub:

> Restarted application in 3.295ms.
> W/DynamiteModule(23950): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
> I/DynamiteModule(23950): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
> W/ProviderInstaller(23950): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
> W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(23950): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message

main.dart:

```
import 'package:app_mypocket/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:app_mypocket/telas/home/homepage.dart';
import 'package:app_mypocket/telas/perfil.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
   //initilization of Firebase app
  
  // other Firebase service initialization

  runApp(MyApp());
}
//final routes = {
 //'/login': (BuildContext context) => new TelaLogin(),
 //'/cadastro': (BuildContext context) => new TelaCadastro(),
 //'/homepage': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
//};

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  //  widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Pocket',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
    ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: error]

Please help!!. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

the getter `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` says:

*You should not use this getter to determine the users current state, instead use [authStateChanges], [idTokenChanges] or [userChanges] to subscribe to updates.*

So, you need listen `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()` to catch user state.

example code to start with that:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
     .userChanges()
     .listen((User user) {
         if (user == null) {
             print('User is currently signed out!');
         } else {
             print('User is signed in!');
         }
});
```

Comment: It worked, but in this case the 'user.email!' stopped working. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: i think its user.currentuser.email